# Eclipse run configuration with complete package name of selected resource as variable

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I am running a Maven project from eclipse and want to setup a Run Configuration with Goals `compile exec:java`, which needs a `exec.mainClass` parameter. Because I have different main classes in my project, I would like class and package name the currently selected resource to be used when running. What are the correct Run Variable to insert as a value for the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following configuration to quickly run the main method of the currently selected class. I know you just asked for the parameters but it I'll provide more detailed steps for other visitors since I didn't found any solution on the net.

Prerequisite: [m2e eclipse plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/), [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)

1. Select *Run as > Maven build …*
2. Use the goal `exec:java`
3. *optional:* provide a profile name
4. *optional:* Select *Debug Output*
5. Click *Add …* to create a parameter

   - Name: `exec.mainClass`
   - Value: `${java_type_name}` (this provides the currently selected resource's full java name)

Now whenever you use this run configuration it will take the current class as parameter and execute its main method. The `${java_type_name}` variable is provided by eclipse, so it should also work somehow without using m2e.

One thing to mention is that the `exec.mainClass` parameter didn't work for me when I provided a goal and default configuration in the *pom.xml*. Not sure if it's a bug, I did something wrong, or simply not possible. I had to remove any goals and just include the plugin without configuring it in the build to make it work:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</plugin>
```